# preg_match for dimension

Tags: php, regex

I trying to get value in 3 dimension measurement like **7.30 x 7.00 x 4.87 mm**
using pre_match php function.

Here is ree`@([0-9\.]+) - ([0-9\.]+) mm x ([0-9\.]+) mm@`

anyone can help me to find what wrong with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `-` should be a `x` and the first `mm` you try to match is not there so you could remove it:

[`([0-9\.]+) x ([0-9\.]+) x ([0-9\.]+) mm`](https://regex101.com/r/DfPAod/1)

Note that `[0-9\.]+` could also match `....`

If the mm is only at the end, you could also try it like this and repeat the `7.30 x` pattern 2 times and match `4.87 mm` at the end.

You could use a word boundary `\b` on the left and the right side.

[`\b(?:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ x ){2}[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ mm\b`](https://regex101.com/r/MZXHg4/1)

```
$re = '@\b(?:[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ x ){2}[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ mm\b@';
$str = 'This is a test 7.30 x 7.00 x 4.87 mm test';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $matches)) {
    echo "Match!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TheFourthBird
your regex helped me.

Comment: this will also match ".. x 12.12 x 12..1 mm"

Comment: @Bernhard That is correct, that is why I added a second regex which would not match `.. x 12.12 x 12..1 mm`

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
preg_match("#[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?\s*x\s*[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?\s*x\s*[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?\s*mm#",$variable);
```

a dimension value is a floating point number, ie composed of one or more digits followed by **[\d]+** optionally one point and one or more digits **(.[\d] +)?** example: **1.45**, **2**,...

The whole optionally followed by one or more spaces **\s*** followed by an **x** character optionally followed by one or more spaces **\s***.

In the end, we add **mm** chain.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this more accurate and also more elegant by using preg_match_all()

```
preg_match_all('/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $input, $matches);

if(count($matches[0]) == 3){
 echo 'match!';
}
```

$matches[0] will output all numbers in an Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2.32
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3.455
        )

)
```